# SQL distinct counts with a lookback window grouped by date

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Trying to find the best way to run a query that has a count by day as well as a column that has a count for the last x days but it's become more complicated then I realized.

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
date(created_at),
count(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS daily_users,
count(
    DISTINCT (
        CASE
        WHEN date(created_at) BETWEEN date_sub(created_at, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
        AND created_at THEN
            user_id
        END
    )
) AS users_2_day_lookback
FROM
table.users
WHERE
date(created_at) BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd'
AND now()
GROUP BY
1
```

But nothing is returning for the 2-day look back column.  I have a feeling this should be done with some sort of outer query that involves a self join possibly but I'm not sure what that syntax would look like.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is a `SQL-Server` question, but rather a `mysql` question. Please remove the tag if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The count-by-day query:

```
select date(created_at),
       count(distinct user_id) as daily_users
from table.users u
group by date(created_at);
```

The two-day lookback is something like this:

```
select dte, daily_users,
       (select count(distinct u2.user_id)
        from table.users u2
        where u2.created_at >= date_sub(dte, interval 2 days) and
              u2.created_at < date_add(dte, interval 1 day)
       ) as users_2_day_lookback
from (select date(created_at) as dte,
             count(distinct user_id) as daily_users
      from table.users u
      group by date(created_at)
      ) u;
```

This query interprets "2-day look back" as the current day plus the two preceding days.  It is easy enough to change the `where` conditions for alternative definitions.